# Need to assoicate an item id from a list with a bootstrap button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of records while cycling through an MVC model (see "for each" loop in code below).

Instead of having an ActionLink and linking to another page, I want to be able to **associate a Bootstrap component to the ID of the record that was clicked** and bring up a modal form.

I know how to bring up and associate the modal form **except for associating the ID value to whatever component I need in the list.**

I'm thinking about *something* like below, but I need some help on the **exact component to use and how to associate the ID value of the record that was clicked.**

The ActionLink with the routevalues & htmlattributes was just an educated guess...

Any help would be *much* appreciated...

```
@model IEnumerable<YeagerTechDB.Models.Category>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CategoryDescription)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryDescription)
        </td>
        <td>
            @*insert a specific bootstrap component instead of actionlinks???*@
            @*when component clicked, assoicate record id in list, bring up modal form and execute associated JS*@
            @*if using just a button below, how do i associate the id of the item that was clicked?*@
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span> Edit
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span>", "Edit", "Edit", routeValues: new { id = item.CategoryID }, htmlAttributes: new { data_modal = "", @class = "btn btn-default" })
            @*@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.CategoryID })*@
         </td>
    </tr>
}

    @*bootstrap modal screen inserted here*@
    @*have hidden id field in modal form*@

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way is using  `data-` attributes. Since you have several buttons that would be used for client side UI on each row, you can use the `<tr>` to store relevant data, or store it on each button.

I don't work in asp much so syntax may not be exact but would look something like:

```html
<tr data-id="<% item.id %>">
```

Then in your button click handlers you can access the row data using:

```js
$('.buttonClass').click(function(){
    var rowId = $(this).closest('tr').data('id');
    /* do stuff with modal */
});
```

Reference: [**data() API docs**](http://api.jquery.com/data/)